# How to find the coordinates of a point on a great circle defined by two known points that is a given distance away.

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

Background: I have three known points: **A**, **B**, and **C**—each with known spherical coordinates, $\rho$ and $\lambda$ on the surface of a sphere of unit radius that form a spherical triangle. I want to find the (spherical) coordinates of the points that are a given distance, **d**, away from one of the three original points, along the great circles of two arcs of the spherical triangle. See (roughly drawn) image:

[Extrapolating arcs of a spherical triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMdgg.png)

Ultimately, I want to find the coordinates of points **a** and **b**, which are the same problem.

I know the values for the coordinates of the other points (**A**, **B**, and **C**) and the arc distance, **d**. I was able to calculate the angle $\theta$ as well, for what it is worth.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie here. I don't know why the MathJax syntax isn't working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See points 2., 3., 4., ... https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Put dollar signs around \rho, \lambda and \theta to render those.

Comment: Thanks to both. I didn't realize that point 2 applied to point 3 (etc.). Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Following your depiction of the situation in the attached image, I will list the
steps for points $C$ and $A$, and the same would follow for point $C$ and $B$.

Step 1:  Write the Cartesian coordinates of $A$ and $C$:

$C = (\sin \theta_C \cos \phi_C, \sin \theta_C \sin \phi_C, \cos \theta_C )$

$A = (\sin \theta_A \cos \phi_A, \sin \theta_A \sin \phi_A, \cos \theta_A )$

Step 2:  Find the cross product between $C$ and $A$ and normalize it

$N = \dfrac{ C \times A }{| C \times A |}$

Step 3:  Find the perpendicular vector $D$ that lies $+90^\circ$ along the great
circle containing $C$ and $A$, as follows,

$D = N \times C $

Step 4:  Now we have two vectors $C$ and $D$ that span the great circle containing $C$ and $A$, therefore, point $a$ can be computed as follows

$a  = (\cos d) C - (\sin d) D$

where a minus sign is used because $a$ is clockwise from $C$ whereas $A$ is anticlockwise.

Step 5: Now that we have the vector $a$ in Cartesian coordinates, we want to find
$\theta_a$ and $\phi_a$, and they can be computed as follows:

$\theta_a = \cos^{-1} a_z $

$ \phi_a = ATAN2( a_x, a_y ) $